# Sequential Promise Throws PromiseRejectionWarnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

#### Situation

I am trying to setup a way of executing promises in a sequential way. I have followed one of the tutorials online and came up with this:

```
  return promises.reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
    return promiseChain.then(chainResults => {
        return currentTask.then(currentResult => {
             return [ ...chainResults, currentResult ];
        }).catch(error => {
          errors.push(error);
          return;
        });
    });
  }, Promise.resolve([])).then(arrayOfResults => {
      console.log("ARRAY_OF_RESULTS", arrayOfResults);
      return errors.length > 0 ? response.status(400).send(errors) : response.status(200).send("De advertenties zijn succesvol verstuurd naar alle partner portalen");
  });
});
```

#### Main file

https://pastebin.com/GLdrKWHp

#### Which promises do I want to sequential resolve and handle errors for?

https://pastebin.com/Ktw6zz9u

#### What is the problem?

> However, somehow, once in a while I get the following warning in my terminal console:

```
(node:10894) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 62)
(node:10894) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 62)
ARRAY_OF_RESULTS undefined
(node:10894) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
(node:10894) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 71)
(node:10894) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 71)
```

> How can we prevent this from happening?

#### Additional info

If you need any additional information or need an invite to the project please do not hesitate to ask me. I know that additional information is probably needed to further debug this question.

#### Update

When I change the return call in the catch of one of my promises like below it won't show the error.

````
```//return { status: error.response.status, partner: "autoscout", message: error.response.statusText };
return Promise.reject({ status: error.response.status, partner: "autoscout", message: error.response.statusText })```
````

Comment: The warning is there because inside the `reduce` callback function you have two promises and you have a `.catch` for only one of them. You can get rid of it by adding a `.catch` to `promiseChain `.

Comment: @Titus can you explain this in detail in an answer on this question?

Comment: @Titus I already tried to add .catches before but that didn't wipe the error message

Comment: Please post the part of your code where you are constructing the `promises` array.

Comment: @Bergi I just updated the question with the route file

Comment: Actually, beside `promiseChain` there is also the result of the `.reduce` function which is a promise and doesn't have a `.catch`.

Comment: @KevinVugts Thanks. But why do you even want those to run sequentially? They don't seem to depend on each other.

Comment: @Bergi are you available for chat? This is way too much to discuss in comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you already have started all of the actions at once, and placed their resulting promises into a `promises` array. Nothing in here is running sequentially. You should just write

```
Promise.allSettled(promises).then(arrayOfResults => {
  console.log("ARRAY_OF_RESULTS", arrayOfResults);
  const errors = arrayOfResults.filter(res => res.status == "rejected").map(res => res.reason);
  if (errors.length > 0)
    response.status(400).send(errors);
  else
    response.status(200).send("De advertenties zijn succesvol verstuurd naar alle partner portalen");
});
```

If you actually wanted to execute your actions sequentially, you would need to start each individual action *inside* the `reduce` callback. Currently, with `currentTask.then(…)` you are only hooking onto the resolution events in sequence, but the actions were started long ago - and when a promise is getting rejected you might not yet have hooked onto it, causing the unhandled rejection. So you'll want to put a *task* - a function that returns a promise - in that array:

```
const tasks = []; // an array of functions to be run sequentially
if(autoscoutEnabled) {
  tasks.push(() => createAutoscoutAd("/vehicles", jsonAutoscout, "tokenteststring"));
  tasks.push(() => addImageToAutoscoutAd("/vehicles/7e59591f-c5a3-974e-e452-2951040ae4ee", file, type, "tokenteststring"));
}

if (marktplaatsEnabled) {
  tasks.push(() => createMarktplaatsAd("/advertisements", jsonMarktplaats, "tokenteststring"));
  tasks.push(() => addImageToMarktplaatsAd("/advertisements/m1427566569", file, type, "tokenteststring"));
}

return tasks.reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
  return promiseChain.then(errors => {
    const currentPromise = currentTask();
// this is the important line         ^^
    return currentPromise.then(() => errors, error => {
      errors.push(error);
      return errors;
    });
  });
}, Promise.resolve([])).then(errors => {
  console.log("ARRAY_OF_RESULTS", arrayOfResults);
  if (errors.length > 0)
    response.status(400).send(errors);
  else
    response.status(200).send("De advertenties zijn succesvol verstuurd naar alle partner portalen");
});
```

However, for sequential execution I would recommend to use `async`/`await`, which is much simple to work with.

Comment: please read this: https://decembersoft.com/posts/promises-in-serial-with-array-reduce/ on the bottom is the explanation

Comment: @KevinVugts That's a horrible page which is confusing a `task` with a `promise`. Yes, there is an `array.reduce` pattern for sequential execution of tasks (I'll edit my answer shortly to include it), but this is not how it works.

Comment: Okey, I am curious :D. I found a lot of similar articles like the one I just sent you.

Comment: This isn't working. currentTask() is not a function error and unhandled promise rejections probably of the "is not a function" error as well.

Comment: @KevinVugts Did you change the code in the conditional to push functions inside that array?

Comment: it does work now. But, I have no clue what fixed the problem to be fairly honest with you... Are you able to explain this in real-easy-language? Maybe with an example?

Comment: Maybe assume that the array always contains 4 items, then try expanding the `reduce` loop. What would the resulting promise chain look like if it was hardcoded? Try inlining the `currentTask()` functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199776/discussion-between-kevin-vugts-and-bergi).